# is Form api ajax attribute good in performance ? does it require an entire bootsrap?

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

Ajax is used for better user experience and also for better performance in a webapp ( change only the requested item instead of the entire page ).

In my case the form will require ajax functionality, interacting live with the Product Configuration Soap Service. 
The performance of this form will be important due to the fact that many users may be accessing it simultaneously.

But how #ajax works in Drupal ? Does It require an entire bootsrap ? If so, will drupal be a good solution in my case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not the request method is AJAX has no bearing on whether a full bootstrap is performed - that's completely down to the behaviour of the *path* that's being requested. If your AJAX call requests '/js/my-page.js', and that menu path is somehow configured not to bootstrap fully, then you won't incur a bootstrap penalty.

To that end, I would highly recommend installing the [High-performance JavaScript callback handler](https://drupal.org/project/js) module.

> JavaScript callback handler is an interim solution for high-performance server requests including (but not limited to) AHAH, AJAX, JSON, XML, etc.
>
> This project targets module developers and provides a "bare bone" callback handler which is intended to be addressed by modules wanting to improve response times for specialized tasks.

It will allow you to define router items for which a full bootstrap will not run; in fact you can pick exactly which modules should be loaded, and which other files should be included, for your callback's requirements.

I've used it before with great success, and have seen very noticeable improvements when converting custom (and even core) AJAX callbacks to use this method. It's blindingly fast.

It also has integration with a bunch of other modules ([SHS](https://drupal.org/project/shs) for example).

As to whether Drupal will be able to handle your project - that's not for us to say; have a look at the various options available (including this one), do some benchmarking and stress testing per your project/client-established requirements, and it'll become apparent whether or not Drupal will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal AJAX calls require Drupal to be bootstrapped all right. You can access anything there is in Drupal when processing calls, so everything needs to be ready.

Basically, Drupal recreates form from scratch, using values provided, and then sends differences to browser. That way you may modify anything about your form to reflect user's actions.

It means AJAX call will not be significantly faster than normal page reload, except the far less amount of data transferred.

As always, custom solution tailored to your use case and gelded from everything you don't need will work faster. As always, developing, debugging and maintaining it will be more expensive.